# Leitura de arquivos sem linha em branco

Tags: python, arquivo

Como faço para evitar a leitura de uma linha em branco em um arquivo, para qualquer sistema operacional, usando a linguagem Python?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
arquivo = open("arquivo.txt", "r")
for linhas in arquivo:
    linhas = arquivo.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar a [função `str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
with open("arquivo.txt", "r") as f:
   linhas = f.read().splitlines()

   for linha in linhas:
       print (linha)
```

Comment: +1 é por isso que gosto do python :D

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar `rstrip()` para isso:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    #Todas as linhas, incluíndo as em branco
    lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f)
    #linhas sem espaço em branco
    lines = (line for line in lines if line)
```

Você pode salvar tudo em uma lista, através do list comphresion:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    names_list = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
```

Note que em um exemplo eu usei `strip` e outro `rstrip`. A função `strip`  ou `rstrip` retornará o valor da string sem espaços em branco. O `if`  vai verificar se o valor resultante da chamada de `strip` ou `rstrip` é vazio. Se não for, a linha é adicionarada na lista, e, se não, é ignorada.

**NOTA**: `rstrip` remove espaços em branco a direita. `strip` remove tanto na esquerda como na direita.

Resposta original no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842057/python-easiest-way-to-ignore-blank-lines-when-reading-a-file);

Comment: No [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) tem como especificar o caractere que você quer remover, ex: `linhas = [linha.rstrip("\n") for linha in f]`

Comment: @zekk interessante! parece com o `rtrim`, `ltrim` e `trim` do php :D

Comment: Isso mesmo, igual o `rtrim`  do PHP.